# if statements for panda dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
timestamp                      0            1            2            3                                           
2013-04-17 05:00:00     4.335212  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854   
2013-04-17 05:10:00     2.224966  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854   
2013-04-17 05:20:00     2.409150  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854   
2013-04-17 05:30:00  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854
```

I need to impose an `if` statement criteria on every value in the dataframe, I have tried using:

```
dirt = dirt.astype(float)
for ind, i in enumerate(dirt):
    if i < 0:
        dirt[ind] = i + 360
    if i > 360:
        dirt[ind] = i - 360
```

However the addition and subtraction are not occurring on any of the values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`.iterrows()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) instead of `enumerate(df)` . When you do `enumerate(df)` you simply get the column names , which would not meet your condition. `iterrows()` returns the index and the row (as a `pandas.Series`) every iteration.

But for your requirement, you can iterate over `df.columns` and do what you want in a vectorized way for every column. Example -

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[col] < 0,col] += 360
    df.loc[df[col] > 360,col] -= 360
```

I am using `columns` instead of `rows` assuming the number of columns would be much less than the number of rows, hence we would be doing the actual loop for much less iterations (and using the vectorized addition for more data simultaneously).

Demo -

```
In [128]: df
Out[128]:
                               0            1            2            3
timestamp
2013-04-17 05:00:00     4.335212  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854
2013-04-17 05:10:00     2.224966  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854
2013-04-17 05:20:00     2.409150  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854
2013-04-17 05:30:00  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854

In [134]: for col in df.columns:
   .....:     df.loc[df[col] < 0,col] += 360
   .....:     df.loc[df[col] > 360,col] -= 360
   .....:

In [135]: df
Out[135]:
                               0            1            2            3
timestamp
2013-04-17 05:00:00     4.335212  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
2013-04-17 05:10:00     2.224966  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
2013-04-17 05:20:00     2.409150  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
2013-04-17 05:30:00  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use masking with [**where**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking) and [**update**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update existing dataframe values like this:

```
In [188]: df
Out[188]: 
                              0            1            2            3
timestamp                                                             
2013-04-1705:00:00     4.335212  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854
2013-04-1705:10:00     2.224966  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854
2013-04-1705:20:00     2.409150  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854
2013-04-1705:30:00  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854  2655.140854

In [189]: df_small = df.where(df < 0).apply(lambda x: x + 360)

In [190]: df_small
Out[190]: 
                     0   1   2   3
timestamp                         
2013-04-1705:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-04-1705:10:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-04-1705:20:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-04-1705:30:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN

In [191]: df_large = df.where(df > 360).apply(lambda x: x - 360)

In [192]: df_large
Out[192]: 
                              0            1            2            3
timestamp                                                             
2013-04-1705:00:00          NaN  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
2013-04-1705:10:00          NaN  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
2013-04-1705:20:00          NaN  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
2013-04-1705:30:00  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
```

---

```
In [193]: df.update(df_small)

In [194]: df.update(df_large)

In [195]: df
Out[195]: 
                              0            1            2            3
timestamp                                                             
2013-04-1705:00:00     4.335212  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
2013-04-1705:10:00     2.224966  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
2013-04-1705:20:00     2.409150  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
2013-04-1705:30:00  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854  2295.140854
```

Note:

This will potentially cater the corner cases if you happen to have conditions like: "value" < 360 then +360 else -360 but the sequence of the update will cause the results reapply, ie. 1 + 360 = 361, then 361 > 360 so it becomes 1 again.

But for your use case, I think @AnandSKumar's method is very clean and close to what you're looking for.